# Run a Python script in the background on boot

Tags: freebsd, python, startup

I recently installed the Google App Engine Development server on my FreeBSD home server to be able to test my GAE app remotely.
What I can't figure out is how to run the Python development server as a background process on boot.

I am running everything in a jail. So, currently, when I want to start the dev server I have to log in to the server, open up the jail and run the Python script manually. Worst thing is that I have to stay connected, because when my laptop loses connection to the jail, the Python process is stopped. I can't figure out a way to run it as a background process / daemon.

In my search of finding a solution (like rc.d, which I don't get at all), I already made a .sh script that runs the command, but I didn't find a way to run that at stratup.

This is the complete command:
`python dev_appserver.py --host=0.0.0.0 --port=2222 /mnt/path/to/gae_app/`

Comment: the `screen` command can run any command in a background that can be connected-to later

Answer (score 1):

> Here what i do in Linux
>   Hop it's help

**Step1: Create a Service**
`sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/NameofYourService.service`

**Step 2:Add This line and edit the locations in Text**

```
[Unit]
Description=Example python App running on Ubuntu

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/app
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/app/app.py
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=Nameofyourapp

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Step3: Enable and start the service**

```
sudo systemctl enable NameofYourService.service
sudo systemctl start NameofYourService.service
```

**for Disable**

```
sudo systemctl stop NameofYourService.service
sudo systemctl disable NameofYourService.service
```

**for logs**

```
sudo journalctl -fu NameofYourService.service
```

## Note:If you use a library in python know that services is running under the root and you need to intstall the library in root

Answer (score 0):

for running your script as a daemon, refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/396655/55744)

for making it on onboot in freebsd refer their official documentation on   [rcorder()(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/rc-scripting/)

Comment: I tried that. I now have a script created in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/` named `gae`. I have added `gae_enabled="YES"` to `/etc/rc.conf`. Still not starting anything at boot.

Comment: @RebelDesigner is it getting listed in the services/daemons that are configured to start at boot?,`ls /etc/rc*.d`

Comment: Yes it is. Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score -1):

you can use cron job

**Step 1** –  Your Python Script path

`/home/app/app.py`

**Step 2** - Open cron using this commands

```
 sudo crontab -e
```

choose your editor mostly nano scroll do at the end

**Step 3** - add this line

```
@reboot python /home/app/app.py
```

**Step 4** - Ctrl+x to exit if you are using nano text editor